# Determine the line integral for the field $F(x,y) = (xy,y^2)$, when $\gamma(t)= (t,t^2)$ and $t \in [0,1].$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Determine the line integral for the field $F(x,y) = (xy,y^2)$, when $\gamma(t)= (t,t^2)$ and $t \in [0,1].$

I have that $$\int_\gamma F \cdot ds = \int_{0}^{1} F(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) \ dt = \int_{0}^{1} (t^3, t^4) \cdot (1,2t) \ dt  = \int_{0}^{1}t^3 +2t^5 \ dt = \frac{7}{12}$$

however, I'm not sure if I should compute  $$\int_{0}^{1} F(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) \ dt$$ or $$\int_{0}^{1} F(\gamma(t)) \cdot \|\gamma'(t)\| \ dt$$

?

Comment: Do you expect the line integral to be scalar or vector?

Comment: The physical intuition is that it tells me how much of the field passes through the line? So scalar?

Comment: Scalar indeed. So what you have computed is correct; the second integral gives you a vector on integration

Comment: You use $\|\gamma'(t)\|$ if you are finding line integral of a scalar field, say, $x^2y$ but if you are finding line integral of a vector field, you have to take $\vec{\gamma'(t)}$ and do dot product with the vector field.